# Creating a scheduled task that runs even if no one is logged in. (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I need to make a "hidden" scheduled task (being created by a .bat, no GUI stuff) that runs when any user is logged in, or if no one is logged in.

Comment: Who are you trying to hide this task from?

Comment: It will execute at a scheduled time specifically or at certain intervals or what per all those requirements. What you are asking sounds like standard Task Scheduler functionality would suffice for those particular needs. Maybe clarify on when this task will be triggered or how that is expected to occur if not on a timed schedule or every x seconds, minutes, etc.

Comment: Maybe this thread can helps solving your issue
https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window

Comment: Maybe this helps to solve your issue https://serverfault.com/questions/9038/run-a-bat-file-in-a-scheduled-task-without-a-window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the .bat file in the startup script in Group Policy.

[image]

Click on "browse" and add your .bat file to it.